# import user defined modules into pydev

Tags: pydev, python-3.6, eclipse-neon

I am a beginner to Eclipse neon + Pydev combo.
Trying to use python modules I created into other modules I will be creating.
For a start, I was going to use TKinter tutorial program outlined here:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm

In addition to printing a statement in response to a mouse click, I want to run a small module, fibo.py

**Here's my code:**

```
import the library
from tkinter import *

import fibo

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()

            self.button = Button(
            frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit
            )
            self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

            self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello",command=self.say_hi)
            self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        fib(100)
        print ("hi there, everyone!")

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
root.destroy() # optional; see description below
```

Here's fibo.py

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
    print (b, end=" ")
    a, b = b, a+b

def fib2(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
    result.append(b)
    a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

Both modules are in the same project and workspace.
The editor says,"unresolved import fibo"
Why is the module fibo not recognized by in pydev/eclipse?

My ultimate goal is to run a module upon button click. If there's a more direct way to accomplish this, I would like to know.

Comment: You probably have some issue in your interpreter configuration... can you post a screenshot of the PyDev package explorer for your project to help diagnose it? (Also, have you gone through the PyDev Getting started? http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html)

Comment: Yes, I went through the getting started guide to configure the editor properly.Not sure how to post images  Fabio. New to this forum as well.

Comment: Here's a link to the screen-shot, Fabio Zadrozny: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rTz9muFfMkRFA2aFlKWVBtTWM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, based on your screenshot, the structure you have is actually:

```
/project (this is the PYTHONPATH root and marked as source folder)
/project/root
/project/root/__init__.py
/project/root/nested
/project/root/nested/__init__.py
/project/root/nested/example.py
/project/root/nested/fibo.py
```

In this case, your import should be: `from root.nested import fibo`. Your code may work in the command line, but that's because you added an entry to `sys.path` only in runtime (so, PyDev can't follow that).

The other option would be moving both example.py and fibo.py to `/project`.

You can also use a relative import as `from . import fibo`, but then, to run the module as a `__main__` module, you'll have to run modules by the module name (with the `-m` flag) -- you can configure PyDev to do that at the `preferences > PyDev > Run > Launch modules with "python -m mod.name"`.

As a note, if you just write:

`fibo` in your case, and wait for the undefined variable error to be shown, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in that same line to get a suggestion which will write the import for you (or you can do a code-completion which will also write an import for you automatically).

Comment: Thank you Fabio. Really appreciate you taking the time to debug this for me. It is now working as expected.

Comment: @sdidde great that it's working for you now ;) As a note, if it answers your question, you should mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I just accepted it the right answer. Hopefully it will show up as such. Thanks again